# Javascript regular expression for one capital

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regular expression for a string that, to be accepted, needs to have the first letter a capital and the other characters are letters. This is what I tried:

```
^[A-Z*[a-z]
```

This doesn't work though.

Answer (score 4):

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+$
```

Is probably what you want. If the other letters can't be uppercase, remove the second `A-Z`.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you minitech, i will accept the answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

Yes @minitech is correct. Although this only specifies the beginning of the string (edit: @minitech's answer has now corrected this). It would match "Adf dfgdfg 6756 #%^^%&". To match only strings containing a capital letter followed by other letters use:

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+$
```

This will match "Aa" but not "A". If you want to match "A" then replace the "+" with "*".